# How to calculate the length of cable on a winch given the rotations of the drum

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

I have a cable winch system that I would like to know how much cable is left given the number of rotations that have occurred and vice versa. This system will run on a low-cost microcontroller with low computational resources and should be able to update quickly, long for/while loop iterations are not ideal.

The inputs are cable diameter, inner drum diameter, inner drum width, and drum rotations. The output should be the length of the cable on the drum.

At first, I was calculating the maximum number of wraps of cable per layer based on cable diameter and inner drum width, I could then use this to calculate the length of cable per layer. The issue comes when I calculate the total length as I have to loop through each layer, a costly operation (could be 100's of layers).

My next approach was to precalculate a table with each layer, then perform a 3-5 degree polynomial regression down to an easy to calculate formula.

This appears to work for the most part, however, there are slight inaccuracies at the low and high end (0 rotations could be + or - a few units of cable length). The real issue comes when I try and reverse the function to get the current rotations of the drum given the length. So far, my reversed formula does not seem to equal the forward formula (I am reversing X and Y before calculating the polynomial).

I have looked high and low and cannot seem to find any formulas for cable length to rotations that do not use recursion or loops. I can't figure out how to reverse my polynomial function to get the reverse value without losing precision. If anyone happens to have an insight/ideas or can help guide me in the right direction that would be most helpful. Please see my attempts below.

```
// Units are not important

CableLength = 15000
CableDiameter = 5
DrumWidth = 50
DrumDiameter = 5

CurrentRotations = 0
CurrentLength = 0
CurrentLayer = 0

PolyRotations = Array
PolyLengths = Array
PolyLayers = Array

WrapsPerLayer = DrumWidth / CableDiameter

While CurrentLength < CableLength // Calcuate layer length for each layer up to cable length
  CableStackHeight = CableDiameter * CurrentLayer
  DrumDiameterAtLayer = DrumDiameter + (CableStackHeight * 2) // Assumes cables stack vertically
  WrapDiameter = DrumDiameterAtLayer + CableDiameter // Center point of cable
  WrapLength = WrapDiameter * PI
  LayerLength = WrapLength * WrapsPerLayer
  
  CurrentRotations += WrapsPerLayer // 1 Rotation per wrap
  CurrentLength += LayerLength
  CurrentLayer++
  
  PolyRotations.Push(CurrentRotations)
  PolyLengths.Push(CurrentLength)
  PolyLayers.Push(CurrentLayer)

End


// Using 5 degree polynomials, any lower = very low precision

PolyLengthToRotation = CreatePolynomial(PolyLengths, PolyRotations, 5) // 5 Degrees
PolyRotationToLength = CreatePolynomial(PolyRotations, PolyLengths, 5) // 5 Degrees

// 40 Rotations should equal about 3141.593 units
RealRotation = 40
RealLength = 3141.593
CalculatedLength = EvaluatePolynomial(RealRotation,PolyRotationToLength)
CalculatedRotations = EvaluatePolynomial(RealLength,PolyLengthToRotation)

// CalculatedLength = 3141.593 // Good
// CalculatedRotations = 41.069 // No good
// CalculatedRotations != RealRotation // These should equal


// 0 Rotations should equal 0 length
RealRotation = 0
RealLength = 0
CalculatedLength = EvaluatePolynomial(RealRotation,PolyRotationToLength)
CalculatedRotations = EvaluatePolynomial(RealLength,PolyLengthToRotation)

// CalculatedLength = 1.172421e-9 // Very close
// CalculatedRotations = 1.947, // No good
// CalculatedRotations != RealRotation // These should equal
```

Side note: I have a "spool factor" parameter to calibrate for the actual cable spooling efficiency that is not shown here. (cable is not guaranteed to lay mathematically perfect)

Comment: Why is  drum width so relevant?

Comment: The point is that wrapping is on a helix around the drum not simple circular layers beside each other. This cause error in accuracy of calculations.You have to consider the length of helix made by winding.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Let's let $n$ be the number of complete layers already laid down, and $t$ be the number of turns in the current (partial) layer, and $s$ be the length of cable currently wound on the spool. Given the other constants (drum diameter, drum width, cable diameter), you'd like

1. A formula that converts $n, t$ into $s$
2. A formula that converts $s$ into $n, t$

each of them without loops if possible, and with the property that

3. if you start with some $n, t$, convert to $s$, and convert back, you get back the same $n, t$ you started with, and if you start with $s$, convert to $(n, t)$, and then back to $s$, you get the same $s$ you started with.

Before I jump into this, I want to observe that property 3 is almost impossible on a computer. If you start with a number $x$, compute its square root, and square that, you'll get back something very close to $x$, but not, in general, actually equal to $x$ -- they'll differ in the 10th or 12th or 20th digit somewhere. So testing for perfect equality of floating-point numbers is always a bad idea. The most you can hope for is approximate equality. Notice, however, that an error in the 20th digit in the reconstructed value for $s$ is hugely smaller than the variation in the length of $s$ due to differing loads on the winch, different temperature (because everything has a temperature coefficient, even your drum!), and probably amounts to something less than a wavelength of light in the cable-length --- a far tinier error than you have in your measurement of your (physical) drum or cable. In short: don't expect equality.

I also want to note that I think your model of cable winding on a spool is probably a bit broken --- unless the diameter of the cable is small compared to the diameter of the drum, you probably want to worry about the fact that individual wraps are not circles, but are helixes. And at the end of a layer, the "climb up" to the next layer isn't really accounted for. Perhaps none of these matters for you, but they are caveats: my answer assumes that your model is a good one, and solves the problems you posed within that context only.

As I said, I'm going to answer the question you asked. Your "side note" at the bottom makes me worry that this will all be of no use. It's incredibly easy to change a problem from one that's easy to solve into one that's impossible. Find an elementary antiderivative for $x \mapsto \exp(-x)$? Easy. Find one for $x \mapsto \exp(-x^2)$? Impossible. I just say this so that you're warned.

---

Letting $w$ be the constant number of turns per full layer, $d$ the drum diameter, and $h$ the rope diameter...here goes.

To convert $(n, t)$ into $s$ (only valid when $t \le w$, of course):

Let's start with a largish value of $n$, to detect a pattern:

Total length on layer 1: $w(\pi(d+h))$

Total length on layer 2: $w(\pi(d+2h))$

Total length on layer 3: $w(\pi(d+3h))$

...

Total length on layer $(n-1)$: $w(\pi(d+(n-1)h))$

Total length on layer $n$: $w(\pi(d+nh))$

Total length on layer n: $t(\pi(d+(n+1)h))$

So the total length on the first $n-1$ layers is
$$
T_1 = \pi w \left[(d + h) + (d + 2h) + \ldots + (d + nh) \right]
$$
Within the brackets, there are $n$ copies of $d$,which I'll gather together:
$$
T_1 = \pi w \left[nd + (h + 2h + \ldots + nh) \right]
$$
and then I factor out an $h$ to get
$$
T_1 = \pi w \left[nd + h(1 + 2 + \ldots + n) \right]
$$
Now I have to pull out a formula, due to Gauss, for the sum of the first $n$ positive integers, namely,
$$
1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{1}{2}(n (n+1)).
$$
So we can write
$$
T_1 = \pi w \left[nd + h(\frac12 n(n+1)) \right]
$$
and then simplify to get
$$
T_1 = \pi w n \left[d + \frac{h(n+1)}{2}\right].
$$
We add to this the total length on the $(n+1)$th layer, which is $t(\pi(d+(n+1)h))$, and we get
\begin{align}
s 
&= T_1 + t(\pi(d+(n+1)h))\\
&= \pi w n \left[d + \frac{h(n+1)}{2}\right] + t(\pi(d+(n+1)h))
\end{align}

At this point, it's nice to divide through by $\pi$ just to make things prettier, and to multiply by $2$ to get rid of fractions; we'll get back to $s$ in a while. So we have
\begin{align}
\frac{2s}{\pi} 
&= 2w n \left[d + \frac{h(n+1)}{2}\right] + 2t(d+(n+1)h)
\end{align}
and now I'm going to just do algebra to expand all of this to be a nicely expressed function of $n$.
\begin{align}
\frac{2s}{\pi} 
&= 2w nd + 2wn \frac{h(n+1)}{2} + 2td + 2th(n+1)\\
&= 2wdn + wnhn + wnh + 2td + 2thn + 2th\\
&= (wh)n^2 + (2wd+ wh + 2th)n + 2td + 2th \\
&= (wh)n^2 + (2wd + wh + 2th)n + 2t(h+d) \\
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
s
&= \frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl( (wh)n^2 + (2wd + wh + 2th)n + 2t(h+d) \Big).
\end{align}

So that's part 1: you can compute the total length $s$ wrapped up in $n-1$ layers with $t$ more turns on the $n$th layer using that formula.

I'm going to rewrite that as a sum of two terms:
\begin{align}
s &= \frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl(wh n^2 + (2wd + wh)n  \Bigr) + 
     \frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl((2th) n + t(2d + 2h)  \Bigr)
\end{align}
Let's call those $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively. $S_1$ is the stuff in the first $n$ (complete) layers; $S_2$ is the length due to the additional $t$ turns on the $(n+1)$st
layer.

Now  suppose we have $s$ and want to find $n$ and $t$. Let's start out by finding $n$. We need the total length of the completed layers to be no more than $s$, i.e., we need to find the largest integer $n$ with $S_1 \le s$. So we're looking for the largest integer $n$ with
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl(wh n^2 + (2wd + wh)n  \Bigr) \le s. \tag{1}
$$
Because the length of the wrapped-up rope is an *increasing* function of $n$ (at least for $n > 0$, which is all we care about), we can find the real number $n_0$ that makes equation 1 into an *equality* --- maybe we find that $6.3$ layers would produce our chosen value $s$. Well, you can't have $6.3$ layers, but the largest whole number of layers you can have that'll fit is $6$ layers, and then you have to compute how many more wraps there will in the 7th layer to get all the way to $s$. So let's change to equality in equation 1, and solve:
\begin{align}
s &= \frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl(wh n^2 + (2wd + wh)n  \Bigr)\\
\frac{2 s}{\pi} &= wh n^2 + (2wd + wh)n \\
0  &= wh n^2 + (2wd + wh)n - \frac{2 s}{\pi}\\
0  &= A n^2 + Bn + C, \text{where}\\
A &= wh\\
B &= (2wd + wh) \\
C &= -\frac{2 s}{\pi}
\end{align}
We can solve this with the quadratic formula, choosing the "plus" part of the plus-or-minus to avoid negative values of $n$, and get
\begin{align}
n_0 
&= \frac{-B + \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}\\
&= \frac{-(2wd + wh) + \sqrt{(2wd + wh)^2 + 4wh \frac{2 s}{\pi}}}{2wh}\\
&= \frac{-(2wd + wh) + \sqrt{(2wd + wh)^2 + 8wh  s/\pi}}{2wh}.
\end{align}
That'll be some typically non-integer number, but we can compute $n$ to be the "floor" of $n_0$, i.e., the result of rounding down to the nearest whole number. (The floor of $3.8$ is $3$; the floor of $7$ is $7$.)

Now knowing $n$, the number of complete layers, we know the length of the cable in those layers is given by $S_1,$ i.e., it's

$$
s_1 = \frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl(wh n^2 + (2wd + wh)n  \Bigr)
$$
Now the remaining part, $s_2$, must be $s - s_1$, so to find $t$, we need to solve
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl((2th) n + t(2d + 2h)  \Bigr) &= s - s_1
\end{align}
for $t$. Let's do it!
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl((2th) n + t(2d + 2h)  \Bigr) &= s - s_1\\
(2th) n + t(2d + 2h)   &= \frac{2}{\pi}(s - s_1)\\
t(2nh) + t(2d + 2h)   &= \frac{2}{\pi}(s - s_1)\\
t(2nh + 2d + 2h)   &= \frac{2}{\pi}(s - s_1)\\
t   &= \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{s - s_1}{2nh + 2d + 2h}
\end{align}
and we're done.

The only remaining question is whether this all works.

It does: here's Matlab code that runs the operations both ways. THe result, when this is run, is to print out 200 zeroes (i.e., the input length and output lengths agree).

```
function test()
for s = 1:200
    [n, t] = layersAndTurns(s); 
    sp = cableLength(n, t); 
    s - sp  % print out the difference between the two values.
end


function s = cableLength(n, t)
% Express total length of cable as a function of the number of complete
% layers, n, and the number, t, of turns on the (n+1)-st layer. Depends on 
% constants d = drum diameter, w = number of turns in a full layer, and 
% h = cable diameter. 
w = 10;
d = 20; 
h = 1; 

s = (pi/2)*( w*h*n^2 + (2*w*d + w*h + 2*t*h)*n + 2*t*(h + d));
%s = (pi/2) * ( w*h * n^2 + (2*w*d - w*h + 2*t*h)*n + 2*(t-w)*d);

function [n, t] = layersAndTurns(s)
% Given the total length of cable, determine the number, n, of full layers 
% on the cable drum, and the number, t, of turns on the next (unfilled)
% layer.  Depends on 
% constants d = drum diameter, w = number of turns in a full layer, and 
% h = cable diameter. 
w = 10;
d = 20; 
h = 1; 

n0 = (-(2*w*d + w*h) + sqrt((2*w*d + w*h)^2 + 8*w*h*s/pi))/(2*w*h);
n = floor(n0); % The whole number of layers that fit. 

s_1 = (pi/2) * (w * h * n^2 + (2*w*d + w*h)* n);
t   = (2/pi) * (s - s_1)/(2*n*h + 2*d + 2*h);
```

Answer (score 1):

The (long) answer I suggested is at least somewhat complicated, and involves a bunch of unverified assumptions. I want to propose an alternative, and this is really an answer about **modelling** rather than algebra or anything like that.

Your drum is going to be able to hold a certain amount of cable. Maybe it'll be 3 layers, maybe 30. I don't recall ever seeing anything drum-like with more layers than that, including substantial industrial cranes, etc. I suppose 100 layers is possible. By the time you get to 1000, you're really talking about "spools" rather than drums -- things like cones of thread. Those seldom use parallel cable layers, instead winding the thread along fairly steep diagonals, etc.

With an upper limit of, say, 100 layers, you can just **measure**. Wind up one layer of  cable, measure how much you've pulled in, and write it down:

```
layer[1] = 37.05
```

Then wind up a second layer, and write down the total pulled in so far:

```
layer[2] = 81.33
```

and keep doing that. Now you don't need to model layer-compaction or anything. You just use those numbers. Knowing that you get $w$ turns per layer, you say that the amount consumed by a turn after the first layer is laid down is `(layer[2] - layer[1])/w`. So if your length is 62, for instance, you say

> Hmm. 62 is bigger than 37.05, but less than 81.33; so $n$ is $1$. That leaves me $62 - 37.05 = 24.95$ units of cable that's in layer-2 wraps. The number of additional turns is therefore $\frac{24.95}{81.33 - 37.05} w$.

And you're done. Now to find out which layer you're in might seem to require testing each `layer[i]` against the total length, but because the values in the `layer` array form an increasing sequence, you can actually use bisection. In a 100-element array, bisection should take no more than 8 steps to find the largest $i$ with `layer[i] < s`. Even on an Arduino, that's not an excessive burden. (After all, the prior method required extracting a square root!)

It's less fun math, but it's probably a lot closer to what you need to get the job done. And I say this as someone who loves math, but has also spent a lot of time modeling real systems, and knows enough to know that simpler is often better than "elegant".